# Concatenate arrays inside of an array - Value Error: Zero dimension arrays cannot be concatenated

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy

I'm trying to append to an existing dataframe 3 new columns which should encode dummy variables.

To do this I am creating a function to look through the array to be "dummied", and for each 'hit' to assign the corresponding value to the to a new row.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

iriss = np.concatenate((np.array(['setosa']*50), np.array(['versicolor']*50), np.array(['virginica']*50)), axis = 0)
```

In this case I present the Iris data set's species column, with 150 equally distributed species (50 units per species).

```
def one_hot_coding():
    one_hot_column = np.array([], dtype = 'int8')

    for one_hot in iriss:
        #my idea here is to find the 'hit = species' and to then for each 'hit' to assign to these
        # three different np.arrays the value of one or zero
        if one_hot == 'setosa':
            one_hot_setosa = np.append(one_hot_column, 1)
            one_hot_versicolor = np.append(one_hot_column, 0)
            one_hot_virginica = np.append(one_hot_column, 0)            
        elif one_hot == 'versicolor':
            one_hot_setosa = np.append(one_hot_column, 0)
            one_hot_versicolor = np.append(one_hot_column, 1)
            one_hot_virginica = np.append(one_hot_column, 0)
        else:
            one_hot_setosa = np.append(one_hot_column, 0)
            one_hot_versicolor = np.append(one_hot_column, 0)
            one_hot_virginica = np.append(one_hot_column, 1)

        one_hot_setosa = np.concatenate((one_hot_setosa), axis = 0)

        print(one_hot_setosa)
one_hot_coding()
```

Results Discussion:

to make it easier I will only talk about `one_hot_setosa`:
when I call `print` on `one_hot_setosa` 150 lines appear where the first 50 lines are [1]'s and the latter 100 [0]'s.

```
[1] [1] ...48 [0] [0] ...48 [0] [0] ... 48
```

From what I see here my results are 150 independent arrays inside of the array called `one_hot_setosa`.

When I try to concatenate them all to obtain a single array (i.e. the `iriss` array created to house the 150 units) I get the following error

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-107-6f70367ed6eb> in <module>
     24 
     25         print(one_hot_setosa)
---> 26 one_hot_coding()

<ipython-input-107-6f70367ed6eb> in one_hot_coding()
     21             one_hot_virginica = np.append(one_hot_column, 1)
     22 
---> 23         one_hot_setosa = np.concatenate((one_hot_setosa), axis = 0)
     24 
     25         print(one_hot_setosa)

<__array_function__ internals> in concatenate(*args, **kwargs)

ValueError: zero-dimensional arrays cannot be concatenated
```

So this error is telling me that I don't actually have 150 arrays, or better said an array`.shape` = (150, 1) (which is what I want). but that actually my array contains nothing? Why is this?

Comment: `np.array(1)` is a 0d array, `np.array([1])` is 1d.

Comment: But I called on the `one_hot_column` which is a `np.array([])`

Comment: `np.concatenate([1,[],[1]])` produces this error because of the initial 1.

Comment: I think I finally understood your answer. for each square bracket I add I add another dimension.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I've been fighting a lot but I managed to solve the problem.

np.concatenate will add rows to the array. So I specified I wanted to add rows to the one_hot_*flower*. Also, as @hpaulj pointed out, square brackets are very important to consider. Since my arrays are 1d arrays I needed to add only square brackets once to the value I wanted to concatenate.

All in all the final code looks like this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

iriss = np.concatenate((np.array(['setosa']*50), np.array(['versicolor']*50), np.array(['virginica']*50)), axis = 0)

one_hot_setosa = np.array([])
one_hot_versicolor = np.array([])
one_hot_virginica = np.array([])

def one_hot_coding():
    global one_hot_setosa
    global one_hot_versicolor
    global one_hot_virginica

    for one_hot in iriss:
        if one_hot == 'setosa':
            one_hot_setosa = np.concatenate((one_hot_setosa, np.array([1])), axis = 0)
            one_hot_versicolor = np.concatenate((one_hot_versicolor, np.array([0])), axis = 0)
            one_hot_virginica = np.concatenate((one_hot_virginica, np.array([0])), axis = 0)            
        elif one_hot == 'versicolor':
            one_hot_setosa = np.concatenate((one_hot_setosa, np.array([0])), axis = 0)
            one_hot_versicolor = np.concatenate((one_hot_versicolor, np.array([1])), axis = 0)
            one_hot_virginica = np.concatenate((one_hot_virginica, np.array([0])), axis = 0)
        else:
            one_hot_setosa = np.concatenate((one_hot_setosa, np.array([0])), axis = 0)
            one_hot_versicolor = np.concatenate((one_hot_versicolor, np.array([0])), axis = 0)
            one_hot_virginica = np.concatenate((one_hot_virginica, np.array([1])), axis = 0)

        #one_hot_setosa = np.concatenate((one_hot_setosa), axis = 0)

    return one_hot_setosa, one_hot_versicolor, one_hot_virginica
one_hot_coding()
```

```
[Out]:
```

```
(array([1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]),
 array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
        0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.,
        1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1., 1.]))
```